# How do I add a Task ID field in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I am trying to have the template of Phabricator's `arc diff` something similar to this:

```
Some title

Summary:

Reviewers:

TaskID: (← missing!)

Subscribers:
```

By default, Phabricator doesn't come with a "TaskID field". Is there any buildin support, or how do I achieve this?

Basically I want to associate a Task ID field with the actual Manifest Task's ID.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Ref T123` (links) or `Fixes T123` (links, and closes when pushed) in the summary, or add `Maniphest Tasks: T123` on its own line. This field is builtin, but the field is not shown by default because most users use the `Ref/Fixes` shorthand.

You could implement `shouldAppearInCommitMessageTemplate()` on `DifferentialManiphestTasksField` to force it to appear on the template. This may be a configurable option after https://secure.phabricator.com/T6030